# Test if AJAX is possible before making request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

If you open an html file on your web browser and the file is on your local computer, lets say `file:///website/XAMPP/index.html`; AJAX request is not possible because the HTML file is not on a server like localhost or webhost and so browser will return an error and possibly break the site functionality.

Q: How can I reliably check if AJAX request is possible before actually making the request?

Comment: you can directly post your ajax on browser console and see status in network tab.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your brower's URL bar or use something like postman. Have you tried Google chrome's [web server add on](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-server-for-chrome/ofhbbkphhbklhfoeikjpcbhemlocgigb)? With it you can easily run your files on a server.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(~["http:", "https:"].indexOf(location.protocol)) {
   // do ajax
}
```